# A weird output?

Tags: c, output

I am new to the C.Sc course and we are taught C program.

I was trying some of the basic stuff. Currently I am learning User-Defined-Function.

The following code is the one I was trying with. I know it is pretty simple but I am not able to understand why it is producing such weird output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a); //function declaration

int main (void)

{
    int b,sum;
    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    sum = add(b); //function calling

    printf("\nSum: %d\n\n", sum);

}

int add(int a) //function definition    

{
    int result;
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)

    {
        result = result + i;
        return result;

    }


}
```

> The output for 1 is 32743
>
> The output for 2 is 32594
>
> The output for 3 is 32704

The weird thing is output change each time for the same number.

It's just weird considering my experience in C.Sc. till date. Kindly explain what the program is doing.

**This is the right place to post problems like this. Right?**

Comment: `int result;` --> `int result = 0;`. Variables with automatic storage are not zeroed. i.e. those kind of variable are stack/register allocated.

Comment: *"Kindly explain what the program is doing"* - it's exhibiting [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) because you haven't initialized `result` before reading from it

Comment: What was the desired output?  I am guessing you want `static int result;` or `int result = 0;`  to return the sum of integers and to place the `return result;` after the loop.  But this is a guess lacking posted expectations.

Comment: Moreover `return result;` must be after the loop

Comment: @chux. But as-it-is now. Why it is producing such weird results. I mean like 32743.... After editing the mistakes I am able to get the desired output.

Comment: @WRI Code reacts in unexpected ways when you do not follow C rules like failing to initialize a variable and then using it.  C is programming without a net - watch your step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to initialize result.

```
int result = 0;
```

**Explanation** : If you do not initialize the variable, it will have a "random" number, and then you are going to get "random" output

**Also** : 
You also forgot to return something if a = 0, or a negatif number !
And your main NEED to return a int.

Also, there is no point to do a loop since you return inside of it, you always going to return 0 in the loop.

Here is a correction of your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a); //function declaration

int main (void)
{
    int b,sum;

    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    sum = add(b); //function calling

    printf("\nSum: %d\n\n", sum);

    return 1;
}

int add(int a) //function definition    
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        result = result + i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Exemple with 10 as input : https://ideone.com/6BjM6y

Comment: Is it true that int main(void) doesn't return anything ?

Comment: `int main(void)` mean that you do not take parameter in input, but it NEED to return an `int`. the other method is to use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`which will take as input the value from command line.

Comment: Hence, I have to return something. I did make a mistake there. right ?

Comment: @WRI indeed, why return 1, just arbitrary value. You need to return a value anyway as "output" of main. Use something like, return, or exit. 1 mean all is good, the program succeed.
Btw, could you validate my answer ?

Comment: But why is the returning necessary in there. I am quite confused with the `main() or  int main(void)` and other sorts of main function syntax. I have read some other questions regarding this but didn't understand much.

Comment: @WRI `int main()` is a default function that is used in eny c++ program. By default, c++ syntax requires it to have a return data type of `int`, even if there is no return statement in it.

Comment: okay! What is meant basically by argument in input ? I am quite confused with this `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @WRI The argument is optional for the `main()` function, and that goes into more advanced topics. You can visit this link: [Arguments](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `result`,

```
int result = 0;
```

In your code, `result` is not initialized so at the

```
result = result + i;
```

line, you use whatever value `result` has and it's not possible to determine which value is that because it's a garbage value.

In c, variables are not automatically initialized for performance reason, with a few exceptions, the most notable are

- Local variables with `static` storage class.
- Global variables.

when you leave a variable uninitialized, then trying to read it's value is considered *undefined behavior*.

#### In response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838280/a-weird-output/42838304?noredirect=1#comment72785817_42838304)

The problem is that you return after adding `0` to `result` which is `0`, so move the `return result;` outside of the `for` loop and it should work.

Comment: I think I did in the function definition.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi. When I intialized result = 0. I am getting Sum: 0 for every Sum : 0 for every input.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi , Shouldnt the result be updated after the loop. Like initially result was 0 and then result is updated to 0 + i where i is succeeding. So, result is to be updated unless the loop is ended. But it did return 0 and updated it to the defined function. Why ? I am confused !

Comment: I don't understand "*updated it to the defined function*", what do you mean?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, I mean within the loop if return result is used the output is `Sum: 0`. What I am asking is, why is it so. Shouldn't the result be updated to the termination of the loop and the final result to be returned.

Comment: @WRI No, `return` terminates the function!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138252/discussion-between-wri-and-iharob-al-asimi).

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable `result`. Since it is bot initialized, the compiler initializes it with a default value, which could be a "*funky"* mumber. To fix this, initialize `result` in your `Add()` function to:

```
int result = 0;
```

**Another thing**: your `return` statement is inside the for-loop. This means that the for-loop will terminate at the end of the *first* loop since there is a return statement that will terminate the function. To fix it, change your function to:

```
int result;
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    result += i; // shorthand way of writing result = result + i. Same end result
}

    return result; // should be outside the loop
```

Comment: @A Busy programmer. I get why it was producing weird outputs after reading your answer. Thank you!